# The attribute 'target' may not appear in tag 'button'

Tags: amp-html

I don't understand why

```
The attribute 'target' may not appear in tag 'button'.
```

How do you open another window with a link/button without

```
target="_blank"
```

Is it performance issue (and how would it be)?

Also, is there a plan B for that kind of problem?

Comment: I know for a fact that `target="_blank"` in a link is valid as almost all of the links in our AMP pages have that attribute.

Comment: Also, here is a [sample page](https://www.google.ca/amp/www.theverge.com/platform/amp/tldr/2016/7/19/12226958/pokemon-go-google-map-display#) I found with `target="_blank"` attribute in its links.

Comment: Actually it seems to be valid on 'a' but not on 'button'.

Comment: What are you using the button for?

Answer (score 0):

`target=_blank` is allowed on the enclosing `<form>` element. Is that enough for what you are going for or do you need different targets for different buttons in the same form?

As an aside, note that the correct attribute in the button tag is actually `formtarget`, (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp), but AMP also does not allow modifying `formtarget` on `<button>` currently either.

I created a github issue for AMP for the `<button formtarget>` attribute [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4216).

Comment: Nice to see the github issue going. Although I fixed this by adding the attribute to <a> (which allows target=) and css'ing it the way the button was. (This is on top of my head, could be wrong). 

Thanks tho.

Comment: The github issue just landed, so this is now resolved, though the attribute to use is `formtarget`, not `target`.